# Healthy way to become numb

Tags: pain, mental-health, treatment, brain, neurology

What can I do to enter a numb state of being so that I don't feel constantly dragged down, fatigue, stress, and all the other downs people experience? For years I've tried exercising, eating healthy, etc. It works to some degree. I get plenty of sleep. I believe the issue is mental. For example, this morning I have a truck load of science experiments to build, but as I sat down to start building them I was swamped with horrible feelings, making it feel like I was carrying a mountain on my shoulders. At least one issue is that I get stressed due to fear of failure. I would much rather spend my entire day thinking. To leave my inner world of thought and actually do physical stuff feels like climbing a tall mountain. It's painful.

Is there anything I can do to numb such sensations? Sometimes I want to be a robot who feels no pain. Perhaps coffee is the answer. Or meditation. Or electric shock therapy lol. Or hyperbaric oxygen therapy. Or joggers high. Or some kind of psychological therapy or hypnosis.

The reason I ask about becoming numb is that twice when life became incredibly horrible I suddenly had the most wonderful blissful sensation of numbness sweep over me. There are no words to describe how wonderful this numbness felt. It didn't last long, about 10 minutes, but during those 10 minutes I could do anything without pain /stress / sadness / fatigue / fear / feeling down. It would be great and more productive to be able to feel like that during my work hours. Thank you so very much for any help!

Comment: If this can be re-worded to not request personal advice, please [edit] and we can see about re-opening. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These could be symptoms of different medical problems, depression, anxiety, or other issues.  In lieu of personal advice or a discussion of treatments, I advise seeing your primary care provider as a starting point for evaluation and management; they can guide you best.

In addition to a medical evaluation, [mindfulness medication](https://www.psychiatry.org/news-room/apa-blogs/apa-blog/2016/06/mindfulness-practices-may-help-treat-many-mental-health-conditions) and deep breathing are techniques commonly used in behavioral health for stress, anxiety, and other issues. They use principles of quieting the external stimuli and internal stimuli and being present in the moment, still, at peace.

However: this would be in addition to, not instead of, seeing a medical professional to evaluate potential causes of your multiple symptoms.

Comment: Hi! Interesting answer. Thanks. Though, do you have some references to backup you claims (in accordance with Health SE policies)? Particularly concerning your claims that _"Cognitive Behavioral Therapy has been shown to be as effective or more effective than medication in both short and long term management of anxiety, PTSD, panic disorder, agoraphobia." I think backuping up this statement with a link to some studies might be useful. Thank you. BW

Comment: Wow thank you! I felt strongly you narrowed in on exactly what the problem is and what I need to hear. The idea of being in the present was an incredible realization to me that makes perfect sense. Also the word "peace" is good description of my two experiences of feeling numb. If there was a supplement to obtain that i would take it in a heartbeat. If practicing mindfulness meditations achieves that as well then I'll do that along with deep breathing. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: ps For a long time I've wanted to see a psychologist. I think with each younger generation this is seen as a healthy normal thing to do. Although it's a bit concerning to find one that's right for me. Some people say they've had horrible experiences with their psychologist while others love theirs. I gather there are good and bad ones.

Comment: Agree with S.Victor. Two questions: 1. why a psychologist and not a psychiatrist? 2. I think it would also be interesting to have some references for the part "ALL humans develop maladaptive patterns to stressful events in their life when growing up that influence their neuropsychological processing of external and internal stimuli throughout life". Finally, if I may: I really don't want to be rude, but even a MD should provide some references to his answer. MDs who publish papers do backup their claims with references. I think this should be the same on health SE. Cheers! Felipe

Comment: @S.Victor and Felipe, I absolutely agree, my apologies, I mistakenly hit post before gathering the links and have had edit window open since,  but was interrupted.  Perhaps I should have pulled the answer and reposted after finishing; I will do so in the future   I've done several informal presentations on the topic and was trying to find my original sources.

Comment: @DoctorWhom. Ok, perfect! BW

Comment: @Felipe - also, never be concerned about being rude by asking that, there is no exception for professionals in backing up statements, and it's on them if they're offended. One challenge is finding the source from my training/education that I learned that information, so I am going back over my posts to ensure the evidence was sufficient.  Recently returned to SE after long hiatus.  I appreciate you upholding standards.

Comment: @Felipe 1. Thank you, edited to clarify, I am not recommending psychology in exclusion of psychiatry.  However, I recommend starting with psychotherapy for reasons above, plus clinical experience and recommendations from PsyD and PhDs on approaches to initial diagnosis/treatment, plus general trends of availability, length and frequency of visits.  Also I would recommend initially primary care over psychiatry, to check overall health for other potential contributing factors. Primary care does treat anxiety/depression and other conditions, and can refer to psychiatry for additional management.

Comment: It is a growing standard of practice in primary care if we start an antidepressant or other medication (OR refer to psychiatry) we also refer to psychology/counseling.  Experientially, in our primary care clinic, at least 1/3 of my patients report some symptoms of depression/anxiety. Our PHQ and GAD screening rates are high. We work side by side with behavioral health practitioners and give warm handoffs right in clinic flow. We actually often actually start treatment with only psychotherapy and monitor improvement, rather than jumping straight to an SSRI etc. I'd be happy to discuss more :)

Comment: Thanks @Doctor Whom for editing your answer with references. I am however not convinced by your answer in general which I find too much advocating CBT in favor of pharmacothery without providing the references for a superiority of CBT over pharmacotherpay.  Also, you say "This sounds very much like depression with components of anxiety." (interesting diagnosis, not sure the question provides all the DSM criteria) but you mainly link evidence (your meta-analysis) for CBT for generalised anxiety disorders and not depression.

Comment: Though, according to uptodate, depression should be first addressed with pharmacotherapy. Furthermore your medscape link states " The combination approach yields superior results for most patients compared to either single modality", which is something which doesn't reflect in your answer where you mainly talk about CBT. Finally, your way of addressing depression/anxiety might be different from other clinics and hospitals.

Comment: Anyway, I think answering those "looking for personal medical advice question" can lead you to a very slippery slope as you really don't have enough background (positive family history? Drug abuse?) to provide a reliable answer. In my opinion, your answer isn't really based on objective evidences (also example "I recommend psychologist for all marriages" --> evidence?). Hope you understand my points. See you soon on other health SE questions! Cheers!

Comment: FYI: your link to the Cochrane Meta-analysis isn't properly formatted and hence doesn't work. Maybe you should consider editing it. Cheers

Comment: @Felipe Thank you, I ALWAYS appreciate advice in refining my participation.  I see your points, and in reviewing it under new light, I feel the bulk of my answer would belong better in another setting entirely.  Especially as there is much more to this that would clarify this approach, but it does not belong here. I will edit accordingly.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Doctor Whom. I am glad you understood my points. +1 for editing your answer. I think this is probably the "best advice" you could give to this very personal question ;-) See you on other Q/A here on health SE. Cheers!